# i have column with decimals and i want it to make it real number please see below

Tags: sql-server

```
NULL
106/1
106/1
87/1
101/1
103/1
104/1
108/1
109/1
105/1
111/1
110/1
100/1
112/1
113/1
114/2
115/2
116/2
117/2
118/1
119/1
120/1
121/1
122/1
124/3
125/3
125/3
126/3
127/3
128/3
```

i want like

```
NULL
106
106
87
101
103
104
108
109
105
111
110
100
112
113
114
115
116
117
118
119
120
121
122
124
125
125
126
127
128
```

Comment: i tried replace but i have to use nested replace and i am actually thought of using pat_index not sure how do i query

Comment: Please also post the query you have used.

Comment: select (replace(column,'/1','') from table. so i have to skip characters after / because i have /2,/3,....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd try to use `SUBSTRING` on this. The `NULL` will cause issues so you'd need to include a `CASE` expression

Test Data

```
CREATE TABLE #TestData (FieldName nvarchar(5))
INSERT INTO #TestData (FieldName)
VALUES
('NULL')
,('106/1')
,('106/1')
,('87/1')
,('101/1')
,('103/1')
,('104/1')
,('108/1')
,('109/1')
,('105/1')
,('111/1')
,('110/1')
,('100/1')
,('112/1')
```

Query

```
SELECT
FieldName
,CASE 
    WHEN CHARINDEX('/',FieldName) > 0
        THEN SUBSTRING(FieldName,1,CHARINDEX('/',FieldName)-1)
    ELSE FieldName
END NewField
FROM #TestData
```

Result

```
FieldName   NewField
NULL        NULL
106/1       106
106/1       106
87/1        87
101/1       101
103/1       103
104/1       104
108/1       108
109/1       109
105/1       105
111/1       111
110/1       110
100/1       100
112/1       112
```

Comment: I think just getting rid of the `NULL` values would be safer.

Comment: Sure, but this will also work if there is any other data in the table without a forward slash. Bearing in mind how the supplied data has been stored in the system I wouldn't be surprised if there was other odd data in there.

Comment: I totally agree and from my experience odd data is always there, especially in `varchar` fields.

Comment: @RichBenner  it works ,  my col has null and left is not working.

Comment: @PranayKumar excellent. I'd say that getting in the habit of using substring is better practice for queries like this. I try to avoid LEFT and RIGHT, not because they're any worse but I feel that people learning substring is going to help more.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the pattern you posted, you can use the following query to get the data in the format you want it:

*(Based on @RichardBenner's answer, it's important to have a `CASE` statement to handle the scenario where you have records that do not match this pattern):*

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN CHARINDEX('/', column, 0) = 0
            THEN column
        ELSE LEFT(column, CHARINDEX('/', column, 0)-1)
    END
FROM TABLE
WHERE column IS NOT NULL
```

But if you want to modify the data in the column you can just change this into a `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE Table
SET Column = CASE 
                WHEN CHARINDEX('/', column, 0) = 0
                    THEN column
                ELSE LEFT(column, CHARINDEX('/', column, 0)-1)
             END
WHERE column IS NOT NULL
```

This will cut out everything after the `/` including the `/` itself, no need for a complex `PATINDEX()`.

*Just to test:*

```
DECLARE @var varchar(10) = '123/4'

SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN charindex('/', @var, 0) = 0
            THEN @var
        ELSE LEFT(@var, charindex('/', @var, 0)-1)
    END
```

Comment: Msg 537, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.                        not sure where im making a mistake ?

Comment: It means that you have data which is not matching this pattern. Possibly you have a record which does not have a `/`.

Answer (score 0):

Find the poisition of `/` using `CHARINDEX` and extract the data before the position of `/` using `LEFT` function

```
Select LEFT(yourcolumn,charindex('/',yourcolumn)-1)
From yourtable
```

Considering you have `/` in all the rows except `NULL` records

Comment: Msg 537, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

Comment: @PranayKumar Then there is a record without `/`. You need to tell what should happen in that case.

Comment: yeah i havve null and i have used query posted by @rich

Comment: @PranayKumar - There is a difference you have string `'NULL'`. My code work fine for Database `NULL`