# UPDATE table SET col = CONVERT(int, col)

Tags: sql-server

I am trying  this

```
UPDATE table
SET col =  CONVERT(int, col)
```

and i am getting

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '106/1' to data type int.

Comment: I don't know what's confusing about the error message.  You have a value `106/1` in your table, which isn't an `int`...  It literally says that in the error message.  Check your data...

Comment: Just curious.  Are you expecting [106 divided by 1] or [106] or [NULL] ?

Comment: I gave you an answer on this the other day http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40870435/i-have-column-with-decimals-and-i-want-it-to-make-it-real-number-please-see-belo replace 'col' with the case statement I gave you and it'll work.

Comment: i am doing vice versa it working . as error one values is failing to do

Comment: @PranayKumar the easiest way to do this is to run an update to convert the data as per your previous question. Once that's done then run your update to convert the column to an int.

Answer (score 3):

If 2012+, you can use TRY_CONVERT()  ... invalid would return NULL

```
UPDATE table SET col = TRY_CONVERT(int, col)
```

If not 2012+

```
UPDATE table SET col = case when isnumeric(col+'.01')=0 then null else CONVERT(int,col) end
```

> Edit (learned that isnumeric() trick last night by Shnugo)

Comment: Thx for the credits :-) [Learned that isnumeric() trick last night myself :-)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40898509/5089204)

Comment: @Shnugo I try to be an honorable man.  A little ashamed I didn't think to add the link.

Answer (score 0):

Check the type of argument you are passing into the method , your method asks for an argument of Type Int but you are giving it as a varchar  that's why its throwing exception.
Try with giving an int once

Comment: Welcome to SO. It helps to post some code to show your answer.